# Unable to publish to SNS from new region

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using a Lambda function to do some processing then when done send out a SNS to be used elsewhere. I have some simple code that is seemingly broken when I deploy to a new region. This should not be an issue since the permissions are for that exact resource not region specific. I have included my code, cloudwatch output and error messages below. I am wondering why it is giving me this error message when it seems to follow the code [example given by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sns-examples-publishing-messages.html) for the AWS SDK for node.js

Only thing I could think of that might be causing this issue is publishing to SNS in a different region is an issue but I don't think it should be since it is specifiying the region in the ARN.

Code:

```
async function sendSNS(message) {
  // Make message useful by making into a string
  let MessageBody = JSON.stringify(message);
  logger.info(`sendSNS Message: ${MessageBody}`);
  // Create publish parameters
  let params = {
    Message: MessageBody,
    TopicArn: process.env.snsARN
  };
  const data = await sns.publish(params).promise()
  return true 
}
```

Cloudwatch output

```
INFO { Message: '{<removed to make clear>}', TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:<account ID>:<topic name>' }
```

Error in cloudwatch:

```
{
    "errorType": "InvalidParameter",
    "errorMessage": "Invalid parameter: TopicArn",
    "code": "InvalidParameter",
    "message": "Invalid parameter: TopicArn",
    "time": "2020-10-08T00:00:21.546Z",
    "requestId": "cb65c64a-fac3-50f7-abb5-91b2a216f3c1",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 20.211126070388417,
    "stack": [
        "InvalidParameter: Invalid parameter: TopicArn",
        "    at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:50:29)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)",
        "    at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
        "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
        "    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)",
        "    at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
        "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
        "    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you set your region `AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});`? its not shown in your question how you define your region or sns.

Comment: @Marcin I have not set that, I did see someone mention that it could be cross region related so I set the region for aws in the lambda function and it made no difference.

Comment: I think that you are using an incorrect topic for the region. For example, you are using us-west-2, but default your SNS client is pointing to us-east-1.
Check your AWS default region that is configured in your code or via AWS Configure.

Comment: @cvekaso It does seem to be region related however changing it via aws region in my lambda function doesn't seem to resolve my issue.

Comment: Is it the function specific issue? What if you use AWS CLI to test the topic from the same region where the lambda is.

Comment: If the function is executing from a different region than the sns topic I'm not sure if setting it in the config will make a difference?

Comment: @Marcin How would I test that? I know adding `--region`  to the command sets the region but this is cross region.

Comment: @nmcdonald This function is in us-west-1 and the sns topic is in us-east-1

Comment: You can start an instance in us-west-1, add the role to it with permissions to sns, and try publishing msg to topic in us-east-1.

Comment: @Marcin I'm trying to stay within Lambda not using EC2 so not sure creating an instance really help. It is for sure not a permissions issue since I can see in the IAM console that it has full access. It seems like AWS isn't accepting the Lambda functions configuration.

Comment: Your code for lambda in question is incomplete. I could try to replicate the issue, but I can't without reproducible example.

Comment: @Marcin The whole lambda has way too much code in it to post here and has code I'm not comfortable posting. In my Lambda I setup AWS/sns with an api version `2010-03-31` and then have a single lambda that does some stuff and if an if statement is true it will await the function in my OP which then calls SNS. The 'message' is a json object which I then parse and use on the other end of the SNS. Not sure what else is needed, I can't see my application logic being needed to see if SNS is the issue.

Comment: You could provide just a [mwe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example) allowing to reproduce the issue. Otherwise, as you see, no one has been able to provide any exact answer, as its only a guessing game at this stage.

Comment: I'm seeing a few other related questions and it seems like you can't publish to an SNS topic from different region: https://serverfault.com/a/909657. I can't find anything about lambda but it's clear in the AWS config docs you can't publish cross region: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/gs-console.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a topic in the Virginia region, and a function in the ohio region and using this code I'm getting the same error as you. I created another function in the Virginia region and put the same code in and It was able to publish the message successfully.

In the SNS FAQ it does say: `You can subscribe your AWS Lambda functions to an Amazon SNS topic in any region.` But that's when choosing to invoke your function from SNS, there seems to be an issue when trying to publish to a topic from a lambda function in a different region.

I'm also seeing other questions with the same results: https://serverfault.com/questions/751912/configure-aws-config-to-send-to-one-global-sns-topic/909657#909657.
I'm not completely confident that this is right, I can't find where they explicitly say that this isn't possible, but after trying the same functionality from one region to another and seeing the other questions answered in a similar way I'm thinking this is either not allowed or it's an issue that needs to be reported to AWS.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const sns = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31'});


exports.handler = async (event) => {    
    await sendSNS("test");
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('execution done'),
    };
};


async function sendSNS(message) {
  // Make message useful by making into a string
  let MessageBody = JSON.stringify(message);
  // Create publish parameters
  let params = {
    Message: MessageBody,
    TopicArn: "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:736234364983:TestNV"
  };
  return sns.publish(params).promise().catch((err)=>{console.error(err)})
}
```