# AWS Lambda Publish Messages to SNS in cross region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a Lambda function (east-us-1) that needs to publish messages to SNS topics in both (east-us-1) & (eu-central-1) regions. Is this possible?

Here is my code snippet. Can someone help on how can I achieve this?
I am surprised to see that the boto3 client documentation says "You can publish messages only to topics and endpoints in the same Amazon Web Services Region"
[Link Here:](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.publish)

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json
import urllib
import boto3

print('Loading message function...')


def send_to_sns(message, context):

    # This function receives JSON input with three fields: the ARN of an SNS topic,
    # a string with the subject of the message, and a string with the body of the message.
    # The message is then sent to the SNS topic.
    #
    # Example:
    #   {
    #       "topic": "arn:aws:sns:REGION:123456789012:MySNSTopic",
    #       "subject": "This is the subject of the message.",
    #       "message": "This is the body of the message."
    #   }

   
    sns = boto3.client('sns')
    sns.publish(
        TopicArn=message['topic'],
        Subject=message['subject'],
        Message=message['body']
    )

    return ('Sent a message to an Amazon SNS topic.')
```

My code throws the following error when SNS is in different region

```
{
    "response": {
        "stackTrace": [
            [
                "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
                28,
                "send_to_sns",
                "Message=message['body']"
            ],
            [
                "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
                357,
                "_api_call",
                "return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)"
            ],
            [
                "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
                676,
                "_make_api_call",
                "raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)"
            ]
        ],
        "errorType": "InvalidParameterException",
        "errorMessage": "An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the Publish operation: Invalid parameter: TopicArn"
    }
}
```

Comment: In the case where it threw the InvalidParameter error, was the SNS topic in a different region?

Comment: @jellycsc sorry i should have called that out. Yes that's correct. SNS is in a different region

Comment: I think you cannot because this is the same with aws config too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64254020/unable-to-publish-to-sns-from-new-region, you might need to create another lambda in the same region for another  sns topic

Comment: @JatinMehrotra is it an aws restriction? or is it just the way the code is written? There is a youtube video that I came across https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RAf6uniKOX4 that says it is possible but somehow when i try to run the code; it does not work

Answer (score 3):

you are facing this issue because of region conflict with below code you can check
your current region

```
my_session = boto3.session.Session()
my_region = my_session.region_name
```

and to solve your problem just do this i am assuming you are connected to us-east-1 and your sns is present in us-east-2 region

```
sns = boto3.client('sns',region_name='us-east-2')
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion have been racking my brain for 2 days on this.; i tried looking for region parameter in the documentation but no luck.